# So how to display message box in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, messagebox, controlsfx

I have read this: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

I don't think 40 lines of code is acceptable to display simple exception message dialog box.

So, how to display dialog boxes in JavaFX? May be ControlsFX can help?

**UPDATE**

Compare how it was done in Swing:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
    "Eggs are not supposed to be green.",
    "Inane error",
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

It is

ONE

LINE

OF

CODE

This is more than enough.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting the count of 40 lines from. It's only 4 or 5 lines of code to do it. You can see that in the example you've provided. If you want to build a more complex custom dialog, then it will be more, but that's to be expected.

Comment: No ControlsFX Dialogs won't help because it is actually what is included in Java 8u40 and above, it will be deprecated if not done yet, read this http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-dialogs/

Comment: It would be easy for you to extend the Alert class and provide a similar method signature as in your Swing example.

Answer (score 12):

You just need to create a new `Alert` with its content set to a `TextArea` inside of a `ScrollPane`, and then add your exception text to the `TextArea`

```
Exception e = new Exception("An exception!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));

Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
alert.setHeaderText("An exception occurred!");
alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(new ScrollPane(new TextArea(sw.toString())));
alert.showAndWait();
```

**UPDATE** to match OP's update:

The equivelant in JavaFX to your Swing example is:

```
new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "This is an error!").showAndWait();
```